# how to fix killed by SIGSEGV (core dumped) error

Tags: linux, assembly, segmentation-fault, x86-64

So i am writing a program in linux x86_64 assembly, the program needs to open a test directory specified in a "section data" , then list the bytes readed from a file with system call "getdents64" , then parse the bytes to get the filenames since "getdents64" returns the number of bytes.

here is the code

```
    global _start

    section .data

    dir : db "test",0
    len: equ 1024       ;define buffer size

    section .bss
    buffer:  resb len   


    section .text

    _start:


;open folder
     mov rax,   2   ;sys_open
     mov rdi,   dir ;folder to open
     mov rsi,   0   ;read only
     mov rdx,   0   
     syscall    

     cmp rax,   0       ;if there is no folder go to exit
     jbe exit

    list:
     mov rdi,   rax     ;directory in rdi
     mov rax,   217 ;sys_getdents64
     mov rsi,   buffer  
     mov rdx,   len     ;length of the buffer
     syscall

     xchg r10,  rax ;save buffer in r10 to loop through it
     xor rax,   rax     ;zero out rax for the next system call
    close:
     mov rax,   3   ;sys_close
     syscall

    find_fname_start:
; look for the sequence 0008 which occurs before the start of a filename 
     add r15,   1   
     cmp r15,   len
     jge exit
     cmp byte [buffer+r15], 
     jnz find_fname_start
     add r15,   1
     cmp byte [buffer+r15], 0x08
     jnz find_fname_start

     xor rcx,   rcx

    find_fname_end:
 ; look for the 00 which denotes the end of a filename 
     add r15,   1           ;
     cmp r15,   len
     jge exit
     mov rdi,   [buffer+r15]        ;<<< PROBLEM
     mov [r15+rcx], rdi
     inc rcx                ;increment offset stored in rcx

     cmp byte [buffer+r15], 0x00    ;denotes end of the filename
     jnz find_fname_end 
     mov byte [r15+rcx],    0x00     ;filename should be in r15

;delete the file

     jmp find_fname_start




    unlink:
    cmp r10,    0   ;if done, exit the program
    jbe exit    
    mov rax,    87  ;sys_unlink
    mov rdi,    buffer  ;list of files 
    syscall
    jmp unlink  

    exit:
    mov rax,    60  ;sys_exit
    mov rdi,    80
    syscall
```

i used gdb to investigate the problem and at the in "find_fname_end", when i try to move byte from a file to a buffer it gets an error
"Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000400136 in find_fname_end ()" 
i put a arrow in code to show you the line that gets this output

Comment: Make sure you used the debugger correctly. My guess is the fault is actually the **next** instruction which says `mov [r15+rcx], rdi`. `rcx` has been zeroed and `r15` is an index so that's unlikely to be a valid address. Also note that you use 64 bit registers all over the place for stuff that is probably just 1 byte each (filename). You don't seem to initialize `r15` at all either.

Comment: @Jester, if r15 isn’t initialized, the fault probably is in the line indicated, since it also uses r15.

Comment: Yeah but earlier code also uses `r15` and also there is a range check on it. Also linux starts your process with most registers zeroed.